# Java - Getting min max numbers with Math.max and Math.min

Tags: java, class, math, max, min

I am creating a program that allows the user to enter as many numbers as they want until they enter 0. Once they enter 0 the console diplays the highest and lowest values entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NumInput {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (;;) {
      System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
      int val = s.nextDouble();
      if ( val == 0) break;
      else continue;
    }

  }
}
```

I don't know how to get the max and min values. I know I should probably use the Math class, but I have no idea how to put it into my code.

Comment: That's what I call a duplicate.

Comment: You don't begin building things by thinking "I know I should use a hammer, I just don't know what for". It's the same with programming: if you get your mind stuck on "I must use Math class" (which is wrong) you will never find the answer. If you want to become a programmer, begin with the problem, not the supposed solution.

Comment: I tried to get additional help, nobody replied so I figured I would make a new question. Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide if you want to use Integer, Long or something else. If you use int values then you should use Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Math.min()` nor `Math.max()`, you can determine extremums dynamically:

```
public class NumInput {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
      System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
      int val = s.nextInt();
      if (min > val) min = val;
      if (max < val) max = val;
    }
    while (val == 0);
    System.out.println(min + " " + max);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this but one is to initialize two variables, say min and max, and assign initialize them with the first value entered. Each value entered after would then get checked to see if higher than max or lower than min. If higher than max, assign the new value to max. If lower than assign the new value to min. You can use Math.max and Math.min to compare if you want.

You could also out all answers into a TreeSet which will naturally order all elements and take the first and the last elements as the min and max respectively.